# What is the application of alloca?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, alloca, stack-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In which cases is alloca() useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452434/in-which-cases-is-alloca-useful)

I recently happened to see the use of alloca() function. A google search told me that it's used to allocate space on the stack. I'm not able to grab the application for it ? Also, are there any pitfalls in using this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `alloca` was never part of any C standard. It has typically been supplied by vendors as an extension to achieve something like the variable-length arrays ("VLA"s) in C99:

```
void foo(int n)
{
    char arr99[n];            // C99-style VLA

    char * p89 = alloca(n);   /* C89 work-around using "alloca" */

    // Usage:
    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
    {
        arr99[i] = p89[i] = '0' + i;
    }

}  // memory is freed automatically here
```

In both cases, the memory is automatically managed and released at the end of the function.

The use of `alloca` is mentally burdensome, since it doesn't quite fit the C object model. For example, even if you allocate the memory in a nested scope, it remains live until the end of the enclosing *function*, not just the block. VLAs have much better semantics, and can be queried with a dynamic `sizeof`, whereas there is no equivalent mechanism for `alloca`-allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

It's handy when you want to do a dynamic-looking allocation (using e.g. a size that varies at run-time), but still be certain it's all cleaned away once the code that calls `alloca()` goes out of scope.

Like all automatic ("stack") allocations, it'll hurt your foot if you accidentally store the pointers longer than they're valid.