# C++ runtime error?

Tags: c++

```
Point V[rows];
```

Is this allowed in C++? `rows` is a variable whose value is given at runtime and `Point` is my class.

Comment: strictly speaking, this would be a compile time error, not a run-time error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only in C99 - it's a new feature called "variable length arrays". Normally, no.

I would strongly recommend against using this feature. If you have to do it, either use alloca, or allocate them properly, i.e. `Point *V = new Point V[rows];`.

BTW: Many people discourage Alloca as well. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018853/why-is-alloca-not-considered-good-practice).

Comment: but then can i acces it as V[i] or not ?

Comment: Yes. A pointer works essentially like an array. You just have to delete the array when you're done.

Comment: Eh, `Point *V = new Point[rows];`, obviously.

Comment: Glad to help! By the way, if you accept this answer, we both get rep points. Good luck with your program!

Comment: Thanks I just did that...i was tring it before thanking u but it said ur suppose to wait

Comment: Assigning the result of a new to a pointer is very bad idea (not exception safe and liable to be leaked by inexperienced users).

Comment: Not a good idea to speak about alloca to people who asks such questions.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ the comparable idiom is:

```
std::vector<Point> V(rows);
```

It's not 100% identical, because it still calls `new Point[]` (c99 can use the stack), but it still gives you the vector without performing multiple allocs.