# Difference between WIN32 and other c string

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I got this code inside a small program to read a file:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)alloca((unsigned int)ui.length);
#else
    unsigned char buffer[ui.length];
#endif
```

Why is a pointer used for Win32 platform and character array for other platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems previously to C99 defining a variable length array on the stack was not supported. alloca essentially does this. Seems this programmer had a WIN32 compiler that didn't support VLA's so was using (the well-supported but non-standard) alloca.

More on this in stack overflow: [Why is the use of alloca() not considered good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018853/why-is-alloca-not-considered-good-practice) and this rather useful array summary http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/Pointers-and-Arrays-page-2 mentioned by Arthur on the stack overflow post.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special in Windows. The difference is Microsoft Visual C++ [does not support](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/333273/request-for-c99-vla-in-visual-studio) [Variable-length array (VLA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (a C99 feature), and the author probably thinks MSVC == WIN32, thus that condition was created.