# Difference between WIN32 and other c string

Tags: c, string, arrays, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between WIN32 and other c string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483209/difference-between-win32-and-other-c-string)

I got this code inside a small program to read a file

```
 #ifdef WIN32  

        unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)alloca((unsigned int)ui.length);
 #else

         unsigned char buffer[ui.length];
 #endif
```

Can anybody tell me , why pointer used for win32 platform and character array for other platform?

Comment: This would be best on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code intended to declare an array of length not known at compile time. It was likely written with the assumption that C++ compilers for Windows targets don't support declaring such arrays (for example, Visual C++ doesn't support that). So when compilation is done for Windows targets `alloca()` function is used to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the compiler used for WIN32 compilation does not support C99 variable length array declarations.