# Is it possible to allocate on stack

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-construction

The `malloc` function always allocate memory on the heap. However, while studying the [Escape Analylis Article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis), I came to know that as an optimization, a compiler can convert heap allocations to stack allocations. For example, if it sees that an allocated memory is only used and then freed inside a function.

Now my question is, is there a way that the programmer can do so himself. That is allocate memory on stack? I know C99 allows a variable to be given as size for an array declaration, but say the programmer wants to resize it. Can it be done?

Comment: *why* do you want to do this?

Comment: C99 does not require you to "allocate at the start". You can "allocate" a VLA anywhere in the code. Resizing is not possible though.

Comment: What do you mean by "not at the start"? What's the point in resizing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`alloca()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca) is what you're looking for. Of course, if you know your structures dimensions statically, it'd be better to use local variables instead.

Comment: You type quicker than me... Anyway, it's worth pointing out [Why is alloca not considered good practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018853/why-is-alloca-not-considered-good-practice) (Your answer is still correct, of course).

Comment: @eran, well, in context of the escape analysis, I suspect that OP want to use that in some sort of a compiler back-end. In this case it should be safe enough to use.

Comment: _Shiver_ : `alloca` is not standard C and offers no advantages over VLAs - it's use should be discouraged as much as possible.

Comment: @paxdiablo, C99 is, unfortunately, also not as standard as it should be - there are many platforms where `alloca()` is available, but no C99. So, if it is for a compiler backend, it would be reasonable to be able to use both.

Comment: C99 _is_ as standard as it should be, it's _the_ standard. I think you may have meant "not as widely supported" :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, yes, indeed, I meant it is not so much a de facto standard .

Comment: I will also prefer to not use anything from C99 that is not supported elsewhere. This VLA thing is not even supported in C++.

Answer (score 4):

C99 also allows you to allocate variable length arrays (VLAs) and other variables at any point within a function, not just at the start, so your point about being able to allocate the memory elsewhere is moot.

You can just plug in a:

```
int arr[somevar];
```

anywhere in the function and have it actioned.

With VLAs, you no longer need to worry about using `malloc/free` (or the infamous `alloca` available on some implementations, which was another way of doing stack-based allocations, the `a` standing for `automatic`) for arbitrarily-located variable-sized allocations.

If you want the ability to resize, you're still going to have to use the standard memory allocation functions like `malloc` and `realloc`. VLAs don't provide that level of functionality (yet).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, converting heap allocations to stack allocations is a library thing, not something that the compiler has any control over. Indeed, on Linux, `malloc` uses the [`brk`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/brk) system call (which resizes the stack) rather than use [`mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap), except for larger pages.

To quote from [the source](http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/trunk/libc/malloc/malloc.c?rev=13698&view=auto):

```
The old goals we kept are
  1) try to get the long lived large allocations to use mmap()
  2) really large allocations should always use mmap()
  and we're adding now:
  3) transient allocations should use brk() to avoid forcing the kernel
     having to zero memory over and over again
```

Comment: Compilers can do it in some cases - see the region analysis implementation in MLkit for example. With C and alike it would be a little bit more problematic due to a non-trivial aliasing analysis.

Comment: `brk` will resize the data segment, not the stack.