# Is the allocation of C++ non pointer data members in pointer class instance on the heap or on the stack

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory

I have a the following class:

```
class CObj {
private:
    MyOtherClass _member;
};
```

and the following code that creates an instance of CObj class:

```
CObj* obj = new Cobj;
```

obj is allocated on the heap, but: Are CObj::_member allocated on the heap too? or on the stack?

Comment: It's a *member* of `CObj`, so what do you think? :)

Comment: Most importantly - why do you care?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`obj` is a pointer allocated "on the stack"; the object `obj` points to is "on the heap", and, being `obj->_member` a member (=a part) of such an object, it's on the heap too.

In general, members, being part of the parent object, are allocated wherever their parent is stored.

Comment: @IvanIshchenko Not enough code to know where it is, but it looks like automatic storage, or "the stack". You are thinking of the thing created by `new`, not `obj` itself.

Comment: As I understood, by obj OP ment an instance of Cobj, not a pointer.

Comment: @IvanIshchenko OP is confused. This is a good opportunity to fix that :)

Comment: Wow, thanks for so much replies I thank all of you for taking your time to my question.

Answer (score 3):

`_member` has *automatic storage duration* - it is allocated where it's owning object is allocated. So, if you create an instance of `CObj` with *dynamic storage duration*, like in your example, it will also be allocated in dynamic storage (the heap). If you create an object with automatic storage duration, it will be on the stack.

The problem with such questions is that C++ does not have any concept of *stack* and *heap* - it's just [storage durations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103145/what-are-exact-requirements-on-automatic-storage-duration).

Comment: `_member` does _not_ have automatic storage duration; it has the storage duration of the object which contains it.

Comment: And of course, it's not just storage durations; there's also object lifetime (which is determined when the constructors and the destructors run).

Answer (score 0):

When you call `new` OS allocate as much memory as size of class on heap and call class contructor.

From this you can see that since `MyOtherClass` is in `CObj` and `CObj` holds `MyOtherClass` , `MyOtherClass`  is also on heap in same space as `CObj` .