# Changing the size of a global array in the main function

Tags: c, list, struct, malloc

I am writing a program that needs to create a variable number of linked lists. The following is declared globally at the beginning of the program:

```
struct Node
{
    int Line;
    struct Node *Next;
} ;

struct Node* Heads[5];
struct Node* Currs[5]; 

int NumOfNames;
```

The first function in `main()` will calculate and store a value for `NumOfNames`. I then need the size of `Heads[5]` and `Currs[5]` to be changed to `Heads[NumOfNames]` and `Currs[NumOfNames]` in order to create `NumOfNames` amount of linked lists. Can anything along these lines be done?

I am quite new to programming and my knowledge of `malloc` and `realloc` is very poor, but I think I somehow need to use these functions in order to achieve my goal.

Thank you for any advice in advance.

Comment: You cannot have globally declared arrays with variable length. Therefore you definitely need to use `malloc` and friends.

Comment: @MichaelWalz So if I understand correctly, when I globally declare `Heads` and `Currs`, memory is being allocated to them. Then, once `NumOfNames` has been calcluated I need to use `realloc` in order to reallocate enough memory for each of the arrays to be of size `NumOfNames`?

Comment: `Heads` is an array, not a pointer.  You cannot invoke `realloc` on an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is [static allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_memory_allocation) and the memory is allocated on stack (actually not really on stack, since these are global variables - see the comments). It means that the size of the array needs to be known at compile time. On the other hand, you want to be able to allocate memory at run time since you don't know the size (`NumOfNames`) earlier. That is called [dynamic allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#DYNAMIC) and you need `malloc` (or `calloc`,...) for that. Such memory is allocated on heap. For more information on this please read e.g. these:

- [Difference between static memory allocation and dynamic memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385322/difference-between-static-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-memory-allocation)
- [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

To do what you want using `malloc` you can do this:

```
struct Node
{
    int Line;
    struct Node *Next;
} ;

struct Node** Heads;
struct Node** Currs; 

int NumOfNames;

int main() {
    // ...
    NumOfNames = 42;
    Heads = malloc(NumOfNames * sizeof(struct Node*));
    Currs = malloc(NumOfNames * sizeof(struct Node*));

    // if you want to allocate the Nodes too...
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NumOfNames; i++) {
        Heads[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        Currs[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    }
    // ...
}
```

When you allocate memory dynamically (using `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`,...), please be sure to [free()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) it as well when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: In the OP's case the variables global variabls and therefore they are not on the stack.

Comment: @MichaelWalz You are right. Global variables are not placed on a stack (but not on heap either). They're still allocated statically though. For further reading on global variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169858/global-memory-management-in-c-in-stack-or-heap

Answer (score 3):

You need this:

```
struct Node
{
    int Line;
    struct Node *Next;
} ;

struct Node** Heads;
struct Node** Currs; 
int NumOfNames ;

main()
{
  int NumOfNames = ... ; // calculate the number of names
  ...
  Heads = malloc(NumOfNames * sizeof (struct Node*));
  // now Heads point to an array of pointers to struct Node of length NumOfNames
  ...
  Heads[1] = malloc(sizeof (struct Node));
  ...
}
```

Comment: This example would be better if it also showed when and how to use realloc.

Comment: Thank you. Where you have `Heads[1] = malloc(sizeof (struct Node));`, does this same line need to be implemented for `Heads[1]` through to `Heads[NumOfNames]`?

Comment: @KOB yes. More precisely to `Heads[0]` to `Heads[NumOfNames - 1]`

Comment: @WilliamPursell not sure why we need `realloc` here.

Comment: Because the question is: 'how to change size?'

Comment: @WilliamPursell, ok but the "how to change size" is about changing the size of the statically allocated array, and as we don't have anymore statically allocated arrays, "changing" the size is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Stop using static arrays, and allocate at runtime instead:

```
struct Node* Heads;
struct Node* Currs; 

Heads = malloc(NumOfNames * sizeof *Heads);
Currs = malloc(NumOfNames * sizeof *Currs);
```

Then you can access `Heads[0]` through `Heads[NumOfNames - 1]` (inclusive), assuming the allocations succeeded of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use C99 (flag `-std=c99` for gcc), then you have [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) available. [Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) too.

```
// From the wikipedia page
float read_and_process(int n)
{
    float vals[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        vals[i] = read_val();
    return process(vals, n);
}
```

Your `Heads` and `Currs` can then use a variable as size. On the other hand, you can't make them global, you'll have to pass pointers and sizes around to sub-functions.

Note also that if you are new to programming and C, the use of `malloc` and `free` is something you really want to learn.

Note also that VLA are [not very popular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326547/is-it-safe-to-use-variable-length-arrays), for example because they don't return errors if you don't have enough memory to allocate space for them, possibly resulting in hard to debug and dangerous problems.

I felt I had to write this alternative, but I also really think you should go for `malloc` and `free`, and learn how this is done. Check if `malloc` returned `NULL` and exit gracefully :)