# Passing multidimensional array in c90 (pre VLA-style)

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given the rise of VLA since `c99` it has become easier to pass a multidimensional array of **unknown size** to a function. But there is a decent amount of controversy around using VLAs. Some readily endorse it ["It is often nicer
  to use dynamic memory, alloca() or VLAs."](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/CODING_STYLE?id=dde8bb32b12c855509777ce52ff59a835155ac78)<sup>1</sup> others [scorne them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326547/is-it-safe-to-use-variable-length-arrays). The question I was asking myself is what the standard way was in the `c90` days to passing a multidimensional array to a function. Here is a little code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

        int arr[2][4];

        int i;
        int j;

        for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                        arr[i][j] = j;
                }
        }    
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I could think of one way: passing a pointer to a pointer:

```
void foo_a(int m, int n, int **ptr_arr)
{
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        ptr_arr[i][j] += 1;
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
}
```

But that would involve flattening the array first by inserting something like into main (which is not pretty).

```
int *unidim_arr[ROW];
for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        unidim_arr[i] = &(arr[i][0]);
}
```

Another one would probably be using a single pointer and calculating the offset by hand which is error prone:

```
void foo_b(int m, int n, int *ptr_arr)
{
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                         *((ptr_arr + i * n) + j) += 1;
                }
        }
}
```

The solution that strikes me as nicest is using something like

```
void foo_c(int m, int n, int (*ptr_arr)[])
{
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        ptr_arr[i][j] += 1;
                }
        }
}
```

but to my understanding this would only work with VLAs where I can simply specify `(*ptr_arr)[n]` in the functions parameter list? Is there another way to do it in `c90` with special attention to `foo_c()`?

<sub>1. Please, no systemd-bashing.</sub>

Comment: You can `void foo_a_10_20(int array[10][20])`!

Comment: Yes, but the idea, and maybe I didn't stress this enough, is that I do not know the size of the array beforehand.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: You need to do the pointer arithmetic correctly yourself. `*(arr + i*n + j)` I'm afraid...

Comment: @Eregrith, a pointer to a pointer to int is not the same as multidimensional array. The indexing uses different arithmetic.

Comment: Indeed [I just tested that on ideone](http://ideone.com/mL7Gyt) and saw I'm wrong

Comment: @StoryTeller has the correct answer. Sir, you should put that in an answer ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to pass a pointer to the first element of the array along with the array dimensions, then treat that pointer as a 1-d array in your function.

Example:

```
void foo( int *arr, size_t r, size_t c )  // process a 2D array defined as int arr[r][c]
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < r; i++ )
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < c; j++ )
      arr[i * r + j] = some_value();  // calculate index manually
}

int main( void )
{
  int arr[4][5];

  foo( &arr[0][0], 4, 5 );
}
```

This scales up pretty easily to higher dimensioned arrays.  Naturally this only works for true multi-dimensional arrays where the rows are all adjacent in memory.  This won't work for arrays dynamically allocated a row at a time, such as

```
int **arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * rows );
for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
  arr[i] = malloc( sizeof *arr[i] * cols );
```

since the rows aren't guaranteed to be adjacent, but in that case you'd just use the `arr` pointer as-is:

```
void bar( int **arr, size_t r, size_t c ) // process a 2D array defined as int **arr
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < r; i++ )
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < c; j++ )
      arr[i][j] = some_value();
}
```

Comment: With your second example involving `malloc()`ed arrays you answered a question I already had lined up in the back of my head. Very nice!