# Array definition by a function parameter

Tags: c, arrays

I've never done this, but I'm not sure why the below array definition is wrong.

I have this example code:

```
typedef struct _SomeObjType {
   int val;
   ...
} SomeObjType;

static SomeObjType *oObject = NULL;
oObject = malloc( sizeof(SomeObjType) );
oObject->val = 300;

static Err foo (SomeObjType *object) {
   if(object == NULL) 
   return -1;

   unsigned char table[object->val];
   ...
}
```

Why is the above array definition in `foo` dangerous?

Comment: It's not _dangerous_ but you need some extra-care (to do not exhaust stack), it's also _wrong_ in C90 but it's allowed in C99 (if array size is unknown at compile-time then you have to use _dynamic arrays_ allocated with malloc).

Comment: See [Is it safe to use variable-length arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326547/is-it-safe-to-use-variable-length-arrays)

Answer (score 2):

It's dangerous in that in C99 and beyond, where you can allocate *variable length arrays* (VLA), there **is no way to tell whether the allocation succeeded**. If it failed, the likely outcome is a crash--or worse, silent data corruption.

Unlike `malloc`, which returns `NULL` when it can't satisfy the request.

Comment: It is just as dangerous as calling a function. You have no way to tell whether there's enough memory for another stack frame.

Comment: Thank you for explanation and about VLA. Now I know new phrase and I still will not use VLA, but malloc as usually.

Comment: @n.m. While this is true for the general case, there is a large class of programs, those without recursive calls, where the maximum stack use is fixed and can be determined through static analysis. This is commonly done for embedded systems, where a stack size must be specified on a per thread/process basis. This static analysis is impossible when VLA are used.