# Structure Arranging in C

Tags: c, structure

I am trying to make a program that will arrange my structures by people ids.
I used long double because IDs are 20 digits long.
For example if I introduce 3 persons:

```
1.Alex Alex / id = 219(...)
2.John John / id = 200(...)
3.Robert Robert / id = 199(...)
```

I want my program to rearrange so Robert comes first, John second and Alex third.
I am having a problem on "for" structure - I don't exactly know how to swap two structures since I have chars and ints combined.

```
typedef struct 
{
    char name;
    char prename;
    long double id;
    int j;
} PERSON;

int main() 
{
    int n,i,j;
    printf ("How many people = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    PERSON v[n];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("For person number nr. %d\n", i);
        printf("name = ");
        scanf("%s", &v[i].name);
        printf("Prename = ");
        scanf("%s", &v[i].prename);
        printf("id = ");
        scanf("%d", &v[i].id);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n-1; j++)
        {
            if( v[i].id > v[j+1].id )
            {
                int temp = v[j].id;
                char temp2[100];
                char temp3[100];

                strcpy(v[j].prename,temp3);
                strcpy(v[j].name,temp2);
                v[j].id = v[j+1].id;
                v[j+1].id = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: You can swap a `struct` like that exactly as you would swap an integer type. Aside: better to use a string for the ID, because not all C implementations support the `long double` type.

Comment: The `sorting` looks like a `bubble sort`. For that, your internal `for` (j) need to start from `i` and not from `0`. The logic is that, for each element on the first `for`, you keep checking if it is greater than the element on the right side and if true, switch.

Comment: A list should be better for your case, you can directly insert in sorted order.

Comment: What's a list in the land of C?  :)  Seriously though, placing the sort into its own function so you can swap it out later would be a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, because there is so many things you've done here that are not obvious to a new C developer, I want to point them out to help you learn:

```
typedef struct 
{
    // These need to be arrays if they are to be strings
    // Preferably using a constant for size or dynamic
    // if you want them to be variable sized to match input.
    char name;
    char prename;
    // Do not use floating point numbers to represent integer values.  
    // IRL, you'd use a library, but here, you may want to use an array of 
    // some sort of integer type instead.
    long double id;  

    // This is a really poor name for a struct variable and probably shouldn't be here.
    int j;
} PERSON;

int main() 
{
    int n,i,j;
    printf ("How many people = ");
    // Dropping raw output from scanf into a memory allocation is crazy dangerous.
    // At least error check the results to be sure it is meaningful.
    scanf("%d", &n);
    // This is a variable length array and often is not supported directly.
    // You probably want to use a malloc()/free() pair to handle this.
    // (Update: VLA is now part of newer standards, but are not safe because they cannot fail gracefully on out of memory.)
    PERSON v[n];

    // Anytime in C I see an array start at 1 and use <= for condition, I get very nervous because
    // it tends to lead to indexing errors.
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("For person number nr. %d\n", i);
        printf("name = ");

        // Oops - and this is why.  You just skipped the first entry at 0
        // and will overwrite memory on the last loop.
        // Also, scanf into a string without a length can blow up memory...
        scanf("%s", &v[i].name);
        printf("Prename = ");
        // Ditto
        scanf("%s", &v[i].prename);
        printf("id = ");
        // Ditto - worse because you've crossed your types - %d doesn't go into a long double.
        scanf("%d", &v[i].id);
    }

    // Should be its own function to make it easier to swap later to a better sort.
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        // Bubble sort usually wants j=i here.
        for(int j=0; j<n-1; j++)
        {
            if( v[i].id > v[j+1].id )
            {
                // Make a swap function here.  Makes it clearer what you want to do.
                int temp = v[j].id;

                // What is 100?  How do you know that is enough?
                // These are called magic numbers and lead to code death.
                char temp2[100];
                char temp3[100];

                // Ah, strcpy - 3 things wrong here.
                // 1 - You have the parameters backwards - you are copying temp3 to your struct.
                // 2 - You have no way to know if the destination will fit the source because it copies until it finds a '\0' - very dangerous.
                // 3 - Because your parameters are backwards and temp123 is not initialized, this very well could copy forever.
                // strncpy (also crazy dangerous) at the least should be used and consider using better means like strlcpy() and such.
                strcpy(v[j].prename,temp3);
                strcpy(v[j].name,temp2);
                v[j].id = v[j+1].id;
                v[j+1].id = temp;

                // You kinda forgot to swap the strings, but the program is already dead so no worries.
            }
        }
    }

    // Please enable compiler warnings - you must return a value here.
    return;
}
```

In seriousness, I'm sure I missed a few other things, but this is good enough for a free internet code review and learning session. :)

Info on strcpy() and strncpy()
[Why is strncpy insecure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869883/why-is-strncpy-insecure)

Info on scanf() safety
[How to prevent scanf causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c)

Info on Variable Length Array safety:
[Is it safe to use variable-length arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326547/is-it-safe-to-use-variable-length-arrays)

Comment: "VLA is now part of newer standards, but are not safe because they cannot fail gracefully on out of memory."  This applies also to any function call as a stack may overflow.  Nominal use of small VLA pose no real "safety" concerns.  OP's use of VLA here is unguarded though and that is a concern.

Comment: More pointing out that VLAs are UB on no memory where malloc/free will at least give a return value you can deal with.  Same for `alloca()`

Comment: The real fun begins when we add error checks to get around these with if statements and then become vulnerable to Spectre attacks :)

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with your code is here:

```
typedef struct
    char name;      <--- just a char! no room for a string
    char prename;   <--- just a char! no room for a string
    long double id;
     int j;
    } PERSON;
```

You need to make these arrays so that they can hold the names.

Like:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 100

typedef struct {
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    char prename[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    long double id;
    int j;
} PERSON;
```

Besides that, you should always check the value returned by `scanf` and **never** do `scanf("%s", &v[i].prename);` as it may lead to buffer overflow. Instead do `scanf("%99s", v[i].prename);` but even better use `fgets`

And for sorting... just use `qsort` - see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html

BTW: A `long double` can't be scan'ed using `scanf("%d", &v[i].id);` - `%d` is for integers. That said, I doubt you want to use `long double`. You probably want some interger type - maybe `long long unsigned` or `uint64_t`

Comment: long double for id hashing is also fun as it may not store the digit he wants directly.  Funny that a long long stores 19 digits perfectly :/.  I wonder if he needs to do some simple BIG MATH here to store the digits he wants instead.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan True... and it's read by `scanf("%d", &v[i].id);` which is another bug

Comment: My security side loves putting a raw scanf input value into a VLA.  What could go wrong?  My god C is a walking booby trap for this crap.