# Stack based array declaration in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, stack-based

In Objective-C, I declare a C array like this:

> int length = 10;
>   int a[length];

This does not cause any errors in Xcode but other compliers like Visual Studio. 
Please tell me how it works. Should I use it or use malloc/calloc instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variable length arrays were introduced in C99. Microsoft's current compiler (VC2010) doesn't support C99 (or at least the VLA part of it) as far as I'm aware.

You *can* use `malloc` to do the same sort of thing, you just have to remember to `free` it when you're done.

Something like:

```
int length = 10;
int *a = malloc (length * sizeof(int));
if (a == NULL) {
    doSomethingIntelligentSinceNoMemoryLeft();
} else {
    useToHeartsContent (a[0], "thru", a[9]);
    free (a);
}
```

You can probably also use `alloca` which is similar to VLAs in that it allocates space on the stack for variables memory blocks.

But you have to be [careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018853/why-is-alloca-not-considered-good-practice). While `alloca` gives you automatic de-allocation on function exit, the stack is usually a smaller resource than the `malloc` heap and, if you exhaust the heap, it gives you back NULL. If you blow out your stack, that will probably manifest itself as a crash.

`alloca(n)` is probably acceptable for small enough values of `n`.

Comment: You can also use `alloca()` to do stack-based allocations with a dynamic size.

Comment: @Kevin: yes, that'll work up to a point, then you'll crash badly as you blow out the stack :-) Although that's probably also the case with VLAs.

Comment: Well explained. Thank paxdiablo.