# how to detect an uninitialized string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a `char x[16]` that I have not initialized, I need to test if something is assigned to`x` or is it how it is created in the run time. how can I do it? Thank you

example code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
char x[16];

 //<other part of the code>
if(x is an empty char array (not assigned anything) then skip the next line) {
 //blank
}else {
//<rest of the code>
}
return 0;}
```

PS: I tried `memchar(x, '\0', strlen(x))`, `if(x[0] == '\0')` and `if(!x[0])` but it doesn't work as I want since char array does not contain `\0` by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must initialize it like this:

```
char x[16] = { 0 }; // note the use of the initializer, it sets the first character to 0, which is all we need to test for initialization.

if (x[0] == 0)
  // x is uninitialized.
else
  // x has been initialized
```

Another alternative, if it is available for your platform, is `alloca`, which allocates data for you on the stack. You would use it like such:

```
char *x = NULL;

if (x == NULL)
    x = alloca(16);
else 
    // x is initialized already.
```

Because `alloca` allocates on the stack, you don't need to `free` the data you allocate, giving it a distinct advantage over `malloc`

Comment: Nice, but that initialization causes all the elements to be initialized to 0, not the first character as your comment states.

Comment: @cnicutar true, but I don't see much of a problem with that considering the OP's question.

Comment: `alloca` is very cool, but it must be used carefully.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1018853/417934 for a discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing variables is a good practice, and you can use the compiler to warn you when they are not. Using gcc, you would use the `-Wuninitialized` flag.

You can initialize your array at compile-time by changing your character array variable like this

`char x[16] = {0};`

and then test to see

```
if ('\0' != x[0])
{
   <do something>; 
}
else
{  
   <initialize character string>;
}
```