# Segmentation fault: Stack allocation in a C program in Ubuntu when bufffer>4M

Tags: c, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, heap-memory, stack-memory

Here's a small program to a college's task:

```
#include <unistd.h>

#ifndef BUFFERSIZE
#define BUFFERSIZE 1
#endif

main()
{
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    int i;
    int j = BUFFERSIZE;

    i = read(0, buffer, BUFFERSIZE);

    while (i>0)
    {
        write(1, buffer, i);
        i = read(0, buffer, BUFFERSIZE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There is a alternative using the stdio.h fread and fwrite functions instead.

Well. I compiled this both versions of program with 25 different values of Buffer Size: 1, 2, 4, ..., 2^i with i=0..30

This is a example of how I compile it:
     gcc -DBUFFERSIZE=8388608 prog_sys.c -o bin/psys.8M

The question: In my machine (Ubuntu Precise 64, more details in the end) all versions of the program works fine:
    ./psys.1M < data

(data is a small file with 3 line ascii text.)

The problem is: When the buffer size is 8MB or greater. Both versions (using system call or clib functions) crashes with these buffer sizes (Segmentation Fault).

I tested many things. The first version of the code was like this:
    (...)
    main()
    {
        char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
        int i;

```
    i = read(0, buffer, BUFFERSIZE);
(...)
```

This crashs when I call the read function. But with these versions:

```
main()
{
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE]; // SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE
    int i;
    int j = BUFFERSIZE;

    i = read(0, buffer, BUFFERSIZE);


main()
{
    int j = BUFFERSIZE; // SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    int i;

    i = read(0, buffer, BUFFERSIZE);
```

Both them crashs (SEGFAULT) in the first line of main. However, if I move the buffer out of main to the global scope (thus, allocation in the heap instead the stack), this works fine:

```
char buffer[BUFFERSIZE]; //NOW GLOBAL AND WORKING FINE
main()
{
    int j = BUFFERSIZE;
    int i;

    i = read(0, buffer, BUFFERSIZE);
```

I use a Ubuntu Precise 12.04 64bits and Intel i5 M 480 1st generation.

```
#uname -a
Linux hostname 3.2.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 10:48:16 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I don't know the OS limitations about the stack. Is there some way to allocate big data in stack, even if this is not a good pratice?

Comment: What does `ulimit -s` give on your system?

Comment: Making `buffer` a global does __not__ allocate it on the "heap". The only way to do that is with `malloc`, `calloc`, etc.

Comment: @AllanDeamon: That means your stack size is limited to 8192 Kbytes (unless you take steps to change this limit).

Comment: ulimit -s newSizeInKB 
this solved my problem. Now how should I proceed with this question?

Comment: I suppose you should accept Joseph Quinsey's answer instead.  You can change which answer is accepted at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack size is quite often limited in Linux. The command `ulimit -s` will give the current value, in Kbytes.  You can change the default in (usually) the file `/etc/security/limits.conf`. You can also, depending on privileges, change it on a per-process basis via the code:

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
// ...
struct rlimit x;
if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &x) < 0)
    perror("getrlimit");
x.rlim_cur = RLIM_INFINITY;
if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &x) < 0)
    perror("setrlimit");
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is pretty simple: if you try to make the buffer too big, it overflows the stack.

If you use `malloc()` to allocate the buffer, I bet you will have no problem.

Note that there is a function called `alloca()` that explicitly allocates stack storage.  Using `alloca()` is pretty much the same thing as declaring a stack variable, except that it happens while your program is running.  Reading the man page for `alloca()` or discussions of it may help you to understand what is going wrong with your program.  Here's a good discussion:

[Why is the use of alloca() not considered good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018853/why-is-alloca-not-considered-good-practice)

EDIT: In a comment, @jim mcnamara told us about `ulimit`, a command-line tool that can check on user limits.  On this computer (running Linux Mint 14, so it should be the same limits as Ubuntu 12.10) the `ulimit -s` command shows a stack size limit of: 8192 K-bytes, which tracks nicely with the problem as you describe it.

EDIT: In case it wasn't completely clear, I recommend that you solve the problem by calling `malloc()`.  Another acceptable solution would be to statically allocate the memory, which will work fine as long as your code is single-threaded.

You should only use stack allocation for small buffers, precisely because you don't want to blow up your stack.  If your buffers are big, or your code will recursively call a function many times such that the little buffers will be allocated many many times, you will clobber your stack and your code will crash.  The worst part is that you won't get any warning: it will either be fine, or your program already crashed.

The only disadvantage of `malloc()` is that it is relatively slow, so you don't want to call `malloc()` inside time-critical code.  But it's fine for initial setup; once the malloc is done, the address of your allocated buffer is just an address in memory like any other memory address within your program's address space.

I specifically recommend against editing the system defaults to make the stack size bigger, because that makes your program much less portable.  If you call standard C library functions like `malloc()` you could port your code to Windows, Mac, Android, etc. with little trouble; if you start calling system functions to change the default stack size, you would have much more problems porting.  (And you may have no plans to port this now, but plans change!)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about `ulimit`.  Thank you for that!  I'll edit my comment to mention it.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: Yeah, this is not the right solution, but this is just a academic experiment, not intended to be used in real word cases. As I gotta to avoid changing the C code as much as possible, so the ulimit -s is the perfect workaround in this very specific case. In real word I'll use dynamic allocation. Thanks