# Why segmentation fault when i want to allocate 8mb on stack

Tags: c++, linux, stack

I get the segmentation fault when i want to allocate this array and output first element. I know that this element not initialized, but why segmentation fault?
Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned long long adj[1024][1024];
    cout << adj[0][0];
    return 0;
}
```

Tested on OSX with(1GB free memory) and on Ubuntu 12.04(with about 15gb free memory).

PS: I was sure that in linux we can allocate big arrays on stack.

Compilers tried:

```
OSX(clang++, g++4.8.3 -std=g++11), Ubuntu(g++4.8.1)
```

ERRORS:

OSX:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

UBUNTU:
    Segmentation fault

Comment: please show the exact error message and also how you compile this tool.

Comment: [This question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908033/) might help.

Comment: Not at a mac right now, but I'm fairly sure the default stack size is 8MB... try raising it with something like `ulimit -s 32768`.

Comment: Because your process doesn't have 8MB in available stack space. Your system installed physical memory has **nothing** to do with this.

Comment: This is strange because i'm sure that i could allocate more memory in stack on olympiads. But can't do it right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default installation of Ubuntu has this limits for user-space processes:

```
$ ulimit -a
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-m: resident set size (kbytes)      unlimited
-u: processes                       16072
-n: file descriptors                1024
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  64
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-x: file locks                      unlimited
-i: pending signals                 16072
-q: bytes in POSIX msg queues       819200
-e: max nice                        0
-r: max rt priority                 0
-N 15:                              unlimited
```

So, the stack size is limited to **8192 KB**. You program needs more, so OS just kill it.

Try to use dynamic allocation for your `adj` array or (not recommended) increase the limit via `ulimit -s 32768` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is very helpful, i know about dynamic allocation, but stack allocation is often uses in competetive programming and olympiads. And i've done it before without problems. So i want to ask, was it always? 8mb default stack size?

Comment: @SukhanovNiсkolay, it depends on a specific Linux distributive. For example, RedHat/Centos use 10240 by default.

Comment: @SukhanovNiсkolay are you sure you've done it with `long long` (which is 8 bytes)? If you change it to `int` (which most often is 4 bytes) it will work quite often.

Comment: Yeah, i'm sure about size. But i'm not sure about distributive. So thanks to all.