# Trivial C++ code... Why does this compile?

Tags: c++, arrays

C++ tutorials like [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/69-dynamic-memory-allocation-with-new-and-delete/) say that the size of all arrays must be decided upon in advance of the program being run. For example, this is not allowed:

```
cout << "How many variables do you want? ";
int nVars;
cin >> nVars;

int anArray[nVars]; // wrong!  The size of the array must be a constant
```

But this trivial program *does* compile and execute fine. *Should* it?

Comment: It compiles, but (at least on gcc 4.8) it triggers [a warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2975fa20de45fe34).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common extension implemented by C++ compilers, such as GNU's g++. Compile with `-std=c++0x` flag to treat such declaration as an error.

Comment: Thanks. So is it stored on the stack, or the heap?

Comment: @user2432701 The array is on the stack. The compiler plays some tricks to know the size.

Comment: @user2432701 They are usually implemented on the stack, that is one of the core reasons many [feel VLAs are evil](http://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/04/07/c99s-vlas-are-evil/) which is similar to the argument [against alloca](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018853/why-is-alloca-not-considered-good-practice).

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I run -pedantic from the command line, then it reports an error. But in CodeBlocks if I check -pedantic it doesn't. Do you happen to know why?

Edit: I've found the solution in case any other reader has the same problem. In code blocks you cannot just hit "build" -- but you actually need to hit "rebuild".

Answer (score 4):

Several compilers including [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla) support variable length arrays as an extension even though this is really a *C99* feature.

If you use the `-pedantic` argument when building with `gcc` or `clang` both will give a warning similar to the following:

```
warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]
```

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't in standard C++ but gcc/g++ and (I believe) MSVC both support extensions for such variable length arrays. There are options you can configure to disable the extensions though, in which case the code wouldn't compile.

In g++ it will fail to compile if you use `-pedantic`.

Answer (score 1):

Modern C/C++ compilers allows to use variable for define array size. Result as same as using alloca().
This is not standard right now, but gcc does this, about another - need to check.