# Does "int size = 10;" yield a constant expression?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, compile-time-constant, variable-length-array

The following code compiles under gcc 4.8 and Clang 3.2:

```
int main()
{
  int size = 10;
  int arr[size];
}
```

8.3.4/1 of the C++ Standard says that the size of an array must be an integral constant expression, which `size` does not seem to be. Is this a bug in both compilers, or am I missing something?

The latest VC++ CTP rejects the code with this interesting message:

```
error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
```

The interesting part is how it seems to think that `size` is zero. But at least it rejects the code. Shouldn't gcc and Clang do the same?

Comment: variable length array is C only not C++. however, gcc and clang support it as extension.

Comment: Could be an extension for variable length arrays proposed in C++1y and/or C99?

Comment: `std::valarray` is proposed in C++1y

Comment: @BryanChen, You're probably thinking of `std::dynarray`, but both that and VLAs are in a TS AFAIK.

Comment: This was one of the more fruitful question I have answered in a while. In trying to beef up my answer on constant expressions I discovered a tidbit on undefined behavior that lead me to this ask and answer [Why do constant expressions have an exclusion for undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319413/why-do-constant-expressions-have-an-exclusion-for-undefined-behavior).

Comment: `size` is not a constant expression because, among other reasons, it can be modified.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) or *VLA* which is a *C99* feature but [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla) support it as an extension in *C++* while Visual Studio [does not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb1574zs.aspx). So `Visual Studio` is adhering to the standard in this case and is technically correct. Not to say that extensions are bad, the [Linux kernel depends on many gcc extensions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gcc-hacks/), so they can be useful in certain contexts.

If you add the `-pedantic` flag both `gcc` and `clang` will warn you about this, for example `gcc` says (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67bafb84ad611631)*):

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'arr' [-Wvla]
  int arr[size];
              ^
```

Using the `-pedantic-errors` flag will make this an error. You can read more about extensions in these documents [Language Standards Supported by GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html#Standards) and [clangs Language Compatibility section](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html).

**Update**

The [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) covers what is a *integral constant expression* in section `5.19` *Constant expressions* paragraph *3* and says:

> An integral constant expression is an expression of integral or unscoped enumeration type, implicitly converted to a prvalue, where the converted expression is a core constant expression. [...]

It is not intuitively obvious from reading this what all the possibilities are but [Boost's Coding Guidelines for Integral Constant Expressions](http://www.boost.org/development/int_const_guidelines.html) does a great job of that .

In this case since you are initializing `size` with a *literal* using *const* would suffice to make it an *integral constant expression* (see [[expr.const]p2.9.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.const#2.9.1)) and also bring the code back to being standard *C++*:

```
const int size = 10;
```

using *constexpr* would work too:

```
constexpr int size = 10;
```

It would probably help to read [Difference between `constexpr` and `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const).

For reference the equivalent section to `8.3.4` paragraph *1* in the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) would be section `6.7.5.2` *Array declarators* paragraph *4* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type. If the size is * instead of being an expression, the array type is a variable length array type of unspecified size, which can only be used in declarations with function prototype scope;<sup>124)</sup> such arrays are nonetheless complete types. If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; **otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type**.