# Simple array memory allocation with size dynamic allocated and predetermined size

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memory-management, dynamic-arrays

I was writing a program and suddenly came through a doubt.
There are two ways i am assigning static array.

```
int main ()
{ 
   int a[10];
}
int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;  //assume i input N as 10
    int a[N];
}
```

How will memory allocation differ in both cases?
Will be assigned during runtime in second case?

Comment: The second version is not allowed in standard C++.

Comment: Or standard C, for that matter

Comment: Could be considered a duplicate of [Does “int size = 10;” yield a constant expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273829/does-int-size-10-yield-a-constant-expression/21273849#21273849), short summary Variable length arrays are valid C99 but are not valid C++ but it is supported as an extension in C++ by several compilers.

Comment: A nitpick, neither of those arrays is 'static'. They are 'auto'.

Answer (score 2):

The second way is not allowed. The first way will create memory on the stack. As soon as main() exits it will be de-allocated. If you want dynamic allocation best way is to use new:

```
int* = new int[N];
```

But then this way you would have to delete it, in the end. If you're OK with using STL then just go with std::vector:

```
std::vector<int> a;
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one is compiled. But it is wrong. Standard C/C++ does not allow it.