# Why doesn't g++ -Wconversion warn about conversion of double to long int when double is constant?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, implicit-conversion

If I pass a double to a function requiring long, g++ warns of conversion problem, but if I pass a const double to a function requiring long, g++ is happy.  The warning is the following:

```
warning: conversion to ‘long int’ from ‘double’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
```

I would like g++ to give me a warning whether I pass a double or a const double.  How would I do so?

I have makefile and some code you can run.  I like to turn on as many warnings as I can, but perhaps one is implicitly shutting off another?  I'm not sure.

Here's the Makefile:

```
WARNOPTS=-Wall -Wextra -pedantic \
      -Wdouble-promotion -Wformat=2 -Winit-self \
      -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum \
      -Wundef -Wunused-function -Wunused-parameter \
      -Wno-endif-labels -Wshadow \
      -Wpointer-arith \
      -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align \
      -Wconversion \
      -Wsign-conversion -Wlogical-op \
      -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls \
      -Wctor-dtor-privacy \
      -Wnarrowing -Wnoexcept -Wstrict-null-sentinel \
      -Woverloaded-virtual \
      -Wsign-compare -Wsign-promo -Weffc++


BUILD := develop
cxxflags.develop := -g $(WARNOPTS)
cxxflags.release := 
CXXFLAGS := ${cxxflags.${BUILD}}

foo: foo.cpp
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Here's foo.cpp:

```
// foo.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const double WAITTIME = 15;  // no warning on function call
//double WAITTIME = 15;  // warning on function call

bool funcl( long time);


bool funcl( long time ) {
  cout << "time = " << time << endl;
  return true;
}





int main() {
  string rmssg;

  funcl( WAITTIME );
  return 0;
}
```

This is the version of g++ that I am using:

```
g++ --version
g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does it warn if you make the constant `15.5`?  I'm guessing that when passing a `double` variable, as it doesn't know what the value is, it gives the warning.  In your case, it "knows" that there won't be any truncation and doesn't complain.

Comment: The reasoning is probably pretty similar to [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21273849/1708801) since `15` is a literal constant expression the compiler can make assumptions about whether the conversion will overflow or not.

Comment: I see.  You guys are right.  If I change the const double with a literal value to 15.5, I get the complaint.  I didn't think to try that because at the function call its just an ordinary double or const double, right?  Anyways, thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a design decision by `gcc` if we look at the [Wconversion wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion), it says:

> [...]The option should not warn for explicit conversions or for cases
>   where the value cannot in fact change despite the implicit conversion.

If we look at the assembly for this code we can see `gcc` is actually using a constant value of `15` instead of a variable which means it is also performing constant folding as well.

Comment: Thanks!  And thanks for the link.  I didn't know that Wconversion had its own wiki!! :)