# C++ initialize array size using constant variable

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, variable-length-array

I noticed that G++ compiler does permit initializing an array like this:

```
vector<vector<string> > partition(string s) {
    const int len = s.size();
    vector<vector<string> > subPalins[len+1] ;
    subPalins[0] = vector<vector<string> >();
    subPalins[0].push_back(vector<string>());
    bool isPalin[len][len];
...
    return subPalins[len];
}
```

The size of array subPalins is len, which is a constant variable. I remember that it is not allowed to initialize a variable-size array since the size of an array must be determined during compiling time. Though len here is a constant, it is still a variable and I don't understand why this is allowed.

Comment: Variable length arrays are allowed in C++ [by extension in gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273829/does-int-size-10-yield-a-constant-expression) this would work in standard C++ if [you used a integer literal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21273849/1708801) the method `size` is not a constexpr function.

Comment: g++ supports C99-style variable-length arrays as an extension.

Comment: `I noticed that G++ compiler does permit initializing an array like this:` If you compiled with `-Wall -pedantic` options, you will see that g++ gives you an error.