# Overloading operator+= for templates with non-type parameter of different sizes

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879007/is-this-a-variable-length-array-or-no) (don't ask why i made a new account) I asked if my test class was creating a VLA. The [answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25879068/4048234) also brought this up:

> One (potentially significant) wrinkle is that `string_test<T, m>` and
>   `string_test<T, n>` are different types when `m != n`.

I can easily fix this by creating a new string_test with the sizes added together. But for operator+= this doesn't work because the size (more accurately, the private data member `buffer[n]`) cannot change.

```
template <typename U, size_t m>
string_test<T, m + n> operator+(const string_test<U, m>& rhs)
{
    char tmp[n + m]; // not VLA, size known at compile-time
    strcpy(tmp, _buffer);
    strcat(tmp, rhs._buffer);
    return make_string(tmp);
}
```

`operator+=` should return a reference and `*this`. What is a way of implementing `operator+=`?

Comment: You want to `+=` a fixed size data structure? What would that even mean?

Comment: Why did you make a new account? :) It's not nice.

Comment: You claim the problem is that `buffer` cannot change, but there is no variable called `buffer` in this code.  Also I don't think the call to `make_string` is useful here.

Comment: Actually, why do you even want a fixed size string like this?  Because I'm not sure you'd want to have a `+=` for a fixed size string class, unless it's merely a fixed size buffer, in which case `+=` should _not_ result in a different type.  In neither case do you have a `+=` that returns a different type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making the size apart of the type, you've told the users of your class that the size of the string is *static* (i.e cannot change). This problem is akin to a simple C-style array (`int x[n]`). Elements cannot be added to the array, instead, one must create a new buffer that can hold the previous elements + the extra elements.

The standard C++ array class [`std::array<T, N>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is implemented in the same way, but it does not provide any insertion operations that would increase the size because it is simply a wrapper around a statically-sized array.