# Cllass functions not resolving nested-class instances or functions

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inner-classes, member-functions

I am writing *member function*s for a `Stack` class. I have a linked list (`LL`) nested-class as a member of the `Stack` class. In the `Stack` constructor, I instantiate a new linked list which calls the `LL` constructor. Using the `LL`'s member functions I generate a new node and point it at the 1<sup>st</sup> stack. This resolves fine.

However, when I am coding a `Stack` member function eclipse no longer resolves the `LL` instance generated in the `Stack` constructor nor the `LL` member function that I am trying to call.

I have tried switching the nested class between `private` and `public` member designations. I also tried to connect the nested-class (`LL`) with it enclosing/parent class (`Stack`) by making the enclosing class a member of the nested class like in the previous question/response:

[Nested Class member function can't access function of enclosing class. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058267/nested-class-member-function-cant-access-function-of-enclosing-class-why)

Neither have had an effect

```
No problems here:
class Stack
{
private:
   int height, top_element;
   class LL
   {
      push_front(string* new_address)
      {
         // ... definition 
      }
      //...  more nested-class members
   };
public:
   Stack(); // constructor
   void push(string); // enclosing class member
};
```

`Stack` constructor is fine as well:

```
Stack::Stack(int size)
{
    height = size;
    top_element = 0;   

    string stack[height];    
    LL stack_map;
    stack_map.push_front(stack);
}
```

When I get here I encounter my problem:

```
void Stack::push(string data)
{
    if (top_element == height - 1)
    {
        string stack[height];           
        stack_map.push_front(stack); // <- PROBLEM
    }
}
```

I hope I did not include too much code. The second block is the demonstrate that the constructor instantiated the `LL` and called `push_front()` no problem while the very next definition complained about the same function and couldn't recognize the instantiated `LL`, `stack_map`

`stack_map` and `push_front` are both underlined in red

```
Symbol 'stack_map' could not be resolved
```

and

```
Method 'push_front' could not be resolved
```

Comment: `string stack[height]` is invalid C++ (use VLA extension).

Comment: `LL stack_map;` is a local variable from your constructor, it is not a class member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mainly two problems!

1. You have an object of `LL` class in the constructor of `Stack`
   class, which is local to the scope, and not available in the member
   function `push`!

   You have

   ```cpp
   LL stack_map;
   ```

   in the scope of the constructor of the class (i.e. `Stack::Stack(int size) {...}`) not in the member functions `void Stack::push(string data)` of the class `Stack`.

   Therefore, when you do

   ```cpp
      stack_map.push_front(stack);
   ```

   in the member function (i.e. `Stack::push`), it is not known to the compiler and hence the error.

   If you want to access the same object of `LL` class (i.e.
   `stack_map`) in other member functions of the `Stack` class, you need to keep it as a member variable of the class.
2. Secondly, [variable length of arrays are not part of the standard
   C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Meaning, the code in the constructor of `stack`

   ```
   string stack[height];
   ```

   should be changed. The better alternative is *[`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of `std::string`'s*.

Meaning, change to

```
#include <vector> // std::vector

class Stack
{
private:
   int height, top_element;
   class LL
   {
   public:
      void push_front(const std::vector<std::string>& new_address) { /* code here */ }
      //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--->> vector of `std::string`
   };
   LL  stack_map; // >>>> `stack_map` member of `Stack`
public:
   Stack(int size)
      : height{ size }
      , top_element{ 0 }
   {
      std::vector<std::string> stack(height);
      stack_map.push_front(stack); //>>>> push_back to the member `stack_map`
   }

   void push(const std::string& str)
   {
      if (top_element == height - 1)
      {
         std::vector<std::string> stack(height);
         stack_map.push_front(stack); //>>>> push_back to the member `stack_map`
      }
   }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Late reply but if I set the Stack member `height` to a constant, couldn't I use that as the array size? It is an int. It is a requirement that the size of stacks is determined by the user and I am also required to generate more stacks (arrays) as the user fills arrays. For that reason I am not using vectors, otherwise your suggestion would make perfect sense. Either way, thank you

Comment: @MagicGAT You can use `string stack[height];`, only when `height` compile-time constants. The [`const` itself is not sufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048025/is-variable-defined-by-const-int-determined-at-compilation-time) for that. "*I am also required to generate more stacks (arrays) as the user fills arrays*": meaning the size of the array is determined at run-time. You could do definitely `string stack = new string[height];` with extra housekeeping works for managing the memory you manually allocated. But, would we prefer to do in C++ that, when we have the `std::vector`?

Answer (score 1):

> The second block is the demonstrate that the constructor instantiated the `LL` and called `push_front()` no problem while the very next definition complained about the same function and couldn't recognize the instantiated `LL`, `stack_map`.

You have a variable named `stack_map` in the onstructor but it is only a function local variable. It is not a member of the class. Because of that, it doesn't exist in `push()`.

Sounds like you need to make that a member variable of the class.

```
class Stack
{
  private:
    int height, top_element;
    class LL
    {
      push_front(string * new_address)
      {
        ... ; // definition 
      }
    };

    LL stack_map;

  public:
    Stack(); // constructor
    void push(string); // enclosing class member
};
```

After you do that, make sure to remove the function local variable from the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, R Sahu. I selected the correct answer only because I had to choose one and it was on top.