# Initializing An Array with a Variable Size

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I am almost done with my code except I need help on two thing. Here is my code: [Code](https://gist.github.com/01f279d8fb7873fc9ae3).  For the function below, I am trying to make it so that I can use the input of "n" to initialize my array, myBits, instead of a constant, which is currently 5.

My Other question is right below that.  I am trying to switch all of the right most bits to "true".  I wrote the for loop in "/* .....*/" but it doesn't seem to be working.  Right above it, I do it long ways for C(5,4)  ....(myBit[0] = myBit[1]....etc...... (I am using this to find r-combinations of strings).... and it seems to work.  Any help would be appreciated!!

```
void nCombination(const vector<string> &Vect, int n, int r){

    bool myBits[5] = { false };  // everything is false now
        myBits[1] = myBits[2] = myBits[3] = myBits[4] = true;

/*  for(int b = n - r - 1; b = n - 1; b++){
        myBits[b] = true;  // I am trying to set the r rightmost bits to true
    }
*/  
    do  // start combination generator
    {
       printVector(Vect, myBits, n);
    } while (next_permutation(myBits, myBits + n));  // change the bit pattern
 }
```

Comment: Use `std::vector<bool> myBits(n, false)`.

Comment: Note that [variable length arrays are not part of standard C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21273829/1708801) an alternative is to use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: What is wrong with my loop in order to set r number of rightmost bits to true??

Answer (score 0):

These are called *variable length arrays* (or VLAs for short) and they are not a feature of standard C++.  This is because we already have arrays that can change their length how ever they want: `std::vector`.  Use that instead of an array and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector<bool>`:

`std::vector<bool> myBits(n, false);`

Then you have to change your `while` statement:

`while (next_permutation(myBits.begin(), myBits.end()));`

You will also have to change your `printVector` function to take a `vector<bool>&` as the second argument (you won't need the last argument, `n`, since a vector knows its own size by utilizing the `vector::size()` function).

As to your program:  If you're attempting to get the combination of `n` things taken `r` at a time, you will need to write a loop that initializes the last right `r` bools to `true` instead of hard-coding the rightmost 4 entries.

```
int count = 1; 
for (size_t i = n-1; i >= 0 && count <= r; --i, ++count)
     myBits[i] = true;
```

Also, you should return immediately from the function if `r` is 0.

Comment: What is wrong with my loop in order to set r number of rightmost bits to true??

Comment: What if `n == r`? The easiest thing to do is loop backwards, starting from `n-1`

Comment: But in the loop i can only use b++.... there is no b--??  How can i go backwards?

Comment: Look at my answer.  The loop is looping from the back to the front by decrementing the index (also, a count is kept to make sure we do this `r` times).