# Passing array as a reference as a parameter using template

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, reference

Since I don't know the size of the array, so I am using `size` as a parameter to pass into my function.

this works:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, size_t N>
void takeArrayParam(T (&myArray)[N]) {
    for(auto i = std::begin(myArray); i != std::end(myArray); i++) {
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int coolArray[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    takeArrayParam<int, 10>(coolArray);
    return 0;
}
```

and this doesn't work (compiler error):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, size_t N>
void takeArrayParam(T (&myArray)[N]) {
    for(auto i = std::begin(myArray); i != std::end(myArray); i++) {
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    size_t size = 10;
    int coolArray[size];
    //int coolArray[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    takeArrayParam<int, size>(coolArray);
    return 0;
}
```

The difference: `coolArray[10]` vs. `coolArray[size]`.

Thanks...

Comment: Why are you passing the template arguments explicitly anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `size` is not a [constant expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression)(*known at compile time*), in your case declaring it using `const` or `constexpr` would fix your issue:

```
constexpr size_t size = 10;
```

Using `const` works in this case since you are initializing with a literal `10` which is a *constant expression*. This is covered in the draft C++ standard section `5.19` *expr.const* which says:

> A conditional-expression is a core constant expression unless it
>   involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression

and includes the following bullet:

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to
>
> - a glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization, initialized
>     with a constant expression, or

Note that array sizes must also be *constant expressions*:

```
int coolArray[size];
              ^^^^
```

As I cover in my answer to [Does “int size = 10;” yield a constant expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21273829/1708801) several compilers support [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)(*VLA*) which is a C99 feature as an extension in C++ but it is not portable, notably Visual Studio does not support VLA.

Comment: What are the cases in which a const variable is a constant expression?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I updated my answer to cover this specific case, I cover the more general case of integral constant expressions in my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21273849/1708801)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `const` to your `size` definition in main().
That's because the size of an array that is allocated on the stack needs to be known at compile time.

Comment: The size of any array needs to be known at the time of its definition. And any template argument needs to be a compile-time constant, regardless of what it's used for.