# Why can't I use a variable to make an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'd like to make array from variable size as following.

```
int buff_size = width*height*3;
unsigned char buffer[buff_size];
```

but I've got an error message like this:

```
mfc_test5Dlg.cpp(418): error C2057: expected constant expression
```

How can I make variable size array?

Comment: Besides your typo, which considering the error seems like not the main issue, VLA is a C99 feature not a C++ feature [some compiler support it as an extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21273849/1708801) but not Visual Studio.

Comment: Your question is tagged with both c and c++. In c++ you cannot do that at all. you can do it in c if you fix syntax errors

Comment: If you want to have a variable or array with dinamic size you may use 'pointers' and 'memory allocation'.

Do some search and you should find examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `;` lying around. Change

```
int buff_size; = width*height*3;
```

to

```
int buff_size = width*height*3;
```

Besides that; if you really want to have an array with variable length; you'll have to allocate it dynamically; You can do this in several ways:

**C++** : new and delete:

```
unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char[buff_size];
...
delete[] buffer;
```

**C** : malloc and free:

```
unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(buff_size); // or malloc(sizeof(char) * buff_size)
...
free(buffer);
```

Comment: This may fix the error but still leaves the OP using a variable length array which is non standard.  They should use a `vector` or `new up an array.

Comment: Considering the error `expected constant expression` I don't believe this is the actual problem.

Comment: You're right; I added that to my answer

Comment: `sizeof(char)` will **never** yield anything else than `1`. It is useless.

Comment: you're right, but I like to keep the habit of putting the sizeof there in order to avoid errors with other types...  I'll add your remark to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. but I've got an error like this. mfc_test5Dlg.cpp(417): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char *' to 'unsigned char *'
          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Build FAILED.

Time Elapsed 00:00:31.40
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: a minor typo: it should be "new unsigned char[buff_size]. I corrected my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can't have variable sized arrays in C++. If you absolutely want to you can dynamically allocate it but using a `std::vector` is almost always better, anyways, this is the dynamic way:

```
int buff_size = width*height*3;
unsigned char* buffer = new char[buff_size];
...

delete[] buffer;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to avoid `new` and `delete` with raw pointers.

```
std::size_t const buff_size = width*height*3u;
```

1) Use `std::vector<char>` if possible:

```
std::vector<char> buffer{buff_size};
```

2) Use `std::make_unique` if available:

```
auto buffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(buff_size);
```

3) Use `std::unique_ptr` manually otherwise:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer{new char[buff_size]};
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern/safe/idiomatic C++ you make variable-size arrays with `vector`:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(buff_size);
```

All other options are unsafe (you either leak memory or access out-of-bounds more easily than necessary).

Comment: Can you explain why using `std::vector<char>::operator[]` is less likely to access the data out of bounds compared to `std::unique_ptr<char[]>::operator[]`? Actually, the other options are less-automated and thus more likely to be used in a wrong manner but that doesn't mean they are unsafe.

Comment: Those operators are equivalent (ignoring the fact that some implementations have bounds-checking in `vector::operator[]` in debug mode). However, consider `vector::at` which performs bounds-checking and should be preferred over `operator[]`. A `unique_ptr<T[]>` offers no such functionality.

Comment: Selecting `at` over `operator[]` usually requires some kind of problem-sensitivity in the first place (so you don't get safety for free... it's just cheapter ;)). Hands down `vector` is easier to use and I generally agree that it should always be preferred and used if possible.