# Why can I set the size of an array equal to the (unknown) size of a vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

my first own question at Stack Overflow:

I am working on a C++ program where something happens that I thought would not work. My colleague is setting up a vector `myvec` of elements of some class we are working with. Its size is chosen by the user on calling the program, so it is not fixed when compiling! Nevertheless, the code includes the following statement which is working:

```
    const unsigned myNumber = myvec.size();
    bool valid_PDFplot[myNumber];
```

I always thought that you cannot define an array of a size that is not already known at compile time unless you are using dynamically allocated memory with `new`? As said above, the size of the vector is not set at compile time as the user has the possibility to add an arbitrary number of elements using `push_back`. Why is the code shown above still working?

Comment: That is an extension to C++ that several compilers support and others don't.

Comment: Related to [Does “int size = 10;” yield a constant expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21273829/1708801)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's accepted because your compiler implements variable-length arrays as an extension.  (VLAs were introduced to standard C in 1999, and made optional in 2011. They've never been added to standard C++.)

If you're using gcc, the `-pedantic` compiler option will cause it to reject the declaration.

```
c.cpp: In function 'int main()':
c.cpp:6:32: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'valid_PDFplot' [-Wvla]
     bool valid_PDFplot[myNumber];
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly the answer I've been looking for. Is it considered bad style if I use this 'feature'?

Comment: @DerAuenlaender: It's not portable, so your code might not compile with another C++ compiler. As a matter of style, if you need variable-length arrays in C++, you should probably be using `std::vector`, or perhaps some other container class.