# Incorrect values when initializing a 2D array to 0 in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, variable-length-array

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int rows = 10;
    int cols = 9;
    int opt[rows][cols] = {0};

         for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                std::cout << opt[i][j] << " ";
            }
             std::cout << "\n";
         }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 32767 1887606704 10943 232234400 32767 1874154647 10943 -1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I'm using gcc 6.3, in https://www.codechef.com/ide

I'm expecting the first row to be all zeros. Shouldn't that be the case?

EDIT: I tested with const variables for rows and cols, and then it initialized to all zeroes. I feel this should throw a compile error instead of exhibiting this incorrect (and potentially dangerous) behavior.

Comment: This `int opt[rows][cols]` is not valid C++ - array sizes must be compile-time constants, not variables.

Comment: Variable length arrays are not supported in C++. If you change `rows` and `columns` to be `const` the problem is fixed.

Comment: @dev_nut Please don't readd the C tag. The question has nothing to do with C...

Comment: C or C++? Please pick one tag

Comment: While [variable length arrays are an extension in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21273829/1708801) gccs docs for VLA does not mention issues w/ initialization.

Comment: I rolled back, because someone changed the variables to const in the original code, which makes the whole question nonsensical. Didn't intend to roll back tags.

Comment: As far as I know, in C99 VLA can't be initialized that way. Not sure how the gcc extension behave in C++, though.

Comment: Interestingly, testing on wandbox, the gcc 4.9.x family all produce all zeros.  Everything above that does not and below says the array cannot be initialized.  It's probably a bug

Comment: Also 1D VLAs seem to be initialized properly. I suggest filing a bug report.

Comment: Even in standard C, you cannot initialize a variable size array — I'm astonished the code compiles at all (but it must be a GCC extension).

Comment: Compiled as C99 code (replacing cout with printf), GCC gives the error `error: variable-sized object may not be initialized`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Concur.  I'm amazed gcc went to such lengths in the first place. just compiling C11 code with clang, VLAs are supported, but specified initialization is likewise *not*. gcc really went the extra mile to support their non-standard extension in C++.

Comment: just use malloc!

Comment: just use calloc!  The `calloc` function sets memory to zeros.  The `malloc` function does not alter the memory; you get what you get.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If we look at the [gcc 4.9 release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html#cxx) it looks like they added support for initializating VLA with the expectation VLA would be supported in a future version of C++:

> G++ supports C++1y variable length arrays. G++ has supported GNU/C99-style VLAs for a long time, **but now additionally supports initializers** and lambda capture by reference. In C++1y mode G++ will complain about VLA uses that are not permitted by the draft standard, such as forming a pointer to VLA type or applying sizeof to a VLA variable. Note that it now appears that VLAs will not be part of C++14, but will be part of a separate document and then perhaps C++17.

We can see [it live that before 4.9](https://wandbox.org/permlink/arWLniq8zmjYMu0x) complains we can't initialize a VLA

```
error: variable-sized object 'opt' may not be initialized  
     int opt[rows][cols] = {0};  
                             ^
```

but in [4.9.1 and after](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wAnnRwaHMATEULCv) it stops complaining and it does not have the same bug we see in more recent [versions](https://wandbox.org/permlink/inSvdWERsxOWqDl3).

So it looks like a regression.

Note that clang refuses to allow initialization of a VLA ([which they support as an extension](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla)) [see a live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oy6lpo9wuTiKdR8A). Which make sense since [C99 does not allow initialization of VLA](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.7.8p3):

> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or an object type *that is not a variable length array type.*

### gcc Bug 69517

gcc [bug report :SEGV on a VLA with excess initializer elements](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69517#c17) has a comment that provides some background on this feature:

> (In reply to Jakub Jelinek from comment #16)
>
> The bug here is in G++ accepting a VLA initializer with more elements than there is room for in the VLA, and then trashing the stack at runtime with the extra elements.  It is a regression with respect to GCC 4.9.3 which implements C++ VLAs as specified in n3639 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3639.html).  This is documented in GCC 4.9 changes (https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html) which highlights the feature using the following example:
>
> ```
>   void f(int n) {
>     int a[n] = { 1, 2, 3 }; // throws std::bad_array_length if n < 3
>     ...
> ```
>
> VLAs were subsequently removed from C++, and also partially (but not completely) removed from G++, which causes C++ programs developed and tested with G++ 4.9 to break when ported to a later version.
>
> C++ VLAs will be safer to use with the patch referenced in comment #9.  It patch had to be reverted from GCC 6.0 because it caused problems in Java.  Java has been removed and I plan/hope to resubmit the patch for GCC 8.  (I wanted to do it for GCC 7 but didn't get to it.)

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a GCC bug, and the desired behavior is most likely that this shouldn't compile. C99 supports variable-length arrays, but refuses to initialize them: C initializers need to know their type at compile-time, but the type of a variable-length array can't be complete at compile-time.

In GCC, C++ gets variable-length arrays as an extension from its C99 support. Therefore, the behavior governing variable-length array initialization in C++ isn't established by a standard. Clang refuses to initialize a variable-length array even in C++.

Note that even `= {0}` is technically sort of dangerous (if it worked at all): if `rows` and `cols` are 0, you'll be overflowing. Memset is probably your best option.

Comment: Since it's C++, `= {}` should work. But in reality it gives me `internal compiler error`. :/

Comment: Note that inside a function, C allows non-constant initializers in non-static (but fixed size) arrays.  Also, neither standard C nor standard C++ allows zero as an array dimension; that too is a GCC extension.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, how do you infer that `= {}` should work? `{}` needs to have the same type as the thing it's initializing, and that type is unknown.

Comment: @zneak Well, it works for 1D VLAs. *"needs to have the same type as the thing it's initializing"* Not sure I understand. It's a braced-init-list, so I expect it to have no type. And the type of the thing we're initializing is known, it's `int[rows][cols]` (which seems to be a 'variably modified type', another GCC extension).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, it does not work in C, and it's not standard C++, and it arguably doesn't really work in non-standard C++ at this point either. It is true that I mixed up implementation details ([Clang gives a type to initializer lists](https://godbolt.org/z/R6hAHA)), but C braced initializers need to have knowledge of the type that they are initializing to support designated initializers, at the very least. I don't think that I need to clarify why I'm calling an incomplete type "unknown".

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question to understand what's wrong with my code or gcc. But, this is how I would do it in C++. Use vectors instead of arrays for variable length array requirements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    int rows = 10;
    int cols = 9;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> opt(rows, std::vector<int>(cols, 0));

         for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                std::cout << opt[i][j] << " ";
            }
             std::cout << "\n";
         }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Or even better, use a single `std::vector<int>` of size `rows * cols`.

Comment: Sure, that would be more cache coherent. I like the double indexing just because it makes more intuitive when dealing with 2D matrics, tables, etc.