# Defining a constant by a variable in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, variables, constants

So I need to define a constant by a variable so I can use that value in the definition of an array. Will this work?

```
std::fstream scores("scores.txt");
int numberOfLines;
std::string temp;

while (std::getline(scores, temp))
{
    numberOfLines++;
}

const int numberOfLines1 = numberOfLines;
int scoresArr [numberOfLines1] = {};
scores.close();
```

Comment: I think you are asking something similar to [Does “int size = 10;” yield a constant expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21273829/1708801)

Comment: No it won't. Use a vector.

Comment: The important part of the requirement is *compile-time*, not *constant*

Answer (score 2):

> Will this work?

Short answer: no.

Long answer.

A C-style array need (in standard C++) a compile-time-known size.

So

```
// ............vvvvvvvvvvvvvv  <-- compile time constant, please
int scoresArr [numberOfLines1] = {};
```

`numberOfLines1` **must** be known compile-time.

Unfortunately, in your code, `numberOfLines1`'s value isn't known compile time but it's clearly uninitialized (so starts with an undefined value)

```
int numberOfLines;  // <-- initialized with an undefined value
```

and incremented a number of times that depends from an external file, so incremented necessarily run-time

```
while (std::getline(scores, temp))
{
    numberOfLines++;
}
```

So: no, doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `int *scoresArr = new int[numberOfLines1];`

and free the space afterwards with `delete [] scoresArr`