# C++ Memory Leak Check

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Will this leak memory:

```
std::string GetStringFromUser(std::string sPrompt, int nMaxBuffSize)
{
    int i, ch;
    char *psBuffer = (char *) _alloca(nMaxBuffSize);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", sPrompt.c_str());
    fflush(stderr);
    for (i = 0; (i < nMaxBuffSize) && ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && (ch != '\n'); i++)
    {
        psBuffer[i] = (char) ch;
    }
    psBuffer[i] = '\0';
    return (std::string) psBuffer;

} // GetStringFromUser()
```

Written by one of my betters, but seems like psBuffer will never get deleted.

Comment: Why the obscure body? Why not just `std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); return line;`? Clearly no memory leaks there.

Comment: On a side note, it seems a bit weird to prompt the user on `stderr`.

Comment: I like it, it's encapsulated. But it does seems that one of your betters got obsessed with doing micro optimizations. If you ever do a profiling against another method using `std::getline` tells us the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no memory leak in this function and using alloca won't cause a memory leak as it's allocated on the stack. From http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Variable-Size-Automatic:

> 3.2.5 Automatic Storage with Variable Size
>
> The function alloca supports a kind of half-dynamic allocation in which blocks are allocated dynamically but freed automatically.
>
> Allocating a block with alloca is an explicit action; you can allocate as many blocks as you wish, and compute the size at run time. But all the blocks are freed when you exit the function that alloca was called from, just as if they were automatic variables declared in that function. There is no way to free the space explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly but fine (I'm assuming `_alloca` is essentially `alloca`).

It is not, however, safe: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018853/why-is-alloca-not-considered-good-practice) for a discussion of possible problems with `alloca`.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it leaks. You need call `free(psBuffer)` to delete it. It is not auto garbage collected.

Also, I doubt `(std::string) psBuffer` will ever work. STL string and C style string a two different container type. STL string use C style string as internal container and will contain a lot more information. So a C style type conversion will not work.

Instead, you should do the following to replace original `return` statement:

```
std::string ret(psBuffer); // <-- content of psBuffer will be copied into string ret.
free(psBuffer);            // <-- garbage collect.
return ret;                // <-- return the correct string.
```

Comment: Memory allocated by `_alloca` is freed automatically (it's on the stack). And `(std::string)psBuffer` will work, calling the `const char *` constructor. Granted, I like `std::string(psBuffer)` a lot better for that.

Comment: `_alloca` is the back bone of `malloc`. It automatically provide storage but there is no garbage collection. There is NO garbage collection in C or C++ unless you're using overloaded `_alloc` which is not likely.

Comment: `alloca` allocates memory on the current stack frame, which means it's freed on return. Also, `std::string` construction from a nul-terminated C string is well-defined.

Comment: @Xephon, What are you talking about? `malloc` allocates memory on the free store and `_alloca` on the stack (at least according to the MSDN page on it, which is the only version of `_alloca` that exists as far as I can tell). Also, `_alloca` isn't even a standard function, so it can't be guaranteed to be the backbone of anything. There's no garbage collection, but stack memory is automatically cleaned up.

Comment: @Xephon Alloca works on the stack, this case does not take into account an stackoverflow (get it get it?) but it will get freed automatically. Garbage Collection has nothing to do with this subject, no one here in C++ knows garbage collection, we clean our S**t ourselves :D