# Why can't we declare an array, say of int data type, of any size within the memory limit?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memory-management

```
int A[10000000]; //This gives a segmentation fault
int *A = (int*)malloc(10000000*sizeof(int));//goes without any set fault.
```

Now my question is, just out of curiosity, that if ultimately we are able to allocate higher space for our data structures, say for example, BSTs and linked lists created using the pointers approach in C have no as such memory limit(unless the total size exceeds the size of RAM for our machine) and for example, in the second statement above of declaring a pointer type, why is that we can't have an array declared of higher size(until it reaches the memory limit!!)...Is this because the space allocated is contiguous in a static sized array?.But then from where do we get the guarantee that in the next 1000000 words in RAM no other piece of code would be running...??

PS: I may be wrong in some of the statements i made..please correct in that case.

Comment: yes, arrays are allocate a contiguous block. The c compiler has absolutely **NO** idea of what the code's actual operating environment is, so if you want a 32gig array, but you're compiling on a 16meg machine, it's not the compiler's job to tell you that you don't have enough memory. Arrays MUSt be contiguous, or a whole bunch of code that uses pointer math would instantly be broken when the array gets split into multiple chunks.

Comment: The first is allocating on the stack, and the stack does not have enough space to hold that much data.

Comment: @clcto what is the upper bound on the stack size? Is that machine dependent?..How do we get surety that int A[1000] is safe enough?

Comment: The size of the stack (and size of the heap) are link time parameters. (they have default sizes if the linker is not told what size to use.).  It seems that the file being executed was not given a link parameter of enough size.   Also, if the OS uses paged memory and the CPU uses address translation, then the stack and heap do not have to be contiguous.

Comment: For local variables, you **are** allowed to declare an array of any size withing the limit, that's the stack size. The same applies to other type of variables

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Firstly, in a typical modern OS with virtual memory (Linux, Windows etc.) the amount of RAM makes no difference whatsoever. Your program is working with virtual memory, not with RAM. RAM is just a cache for virtual memory access. The absolute limiting factor for maximum array size is not RAM, it is the size of the available *address space*. Address space is the resource you have to worry about in OSes with virtual memory. In 32-bit OSes you have 4 gigabytes of address space, part of which is taken up for various household needs and the rest is available to you. In 64-bit OSes you theoretically have 16 exabytes of address space (less than that in practical implementations, since CPUs usually use less than 64 bits to represent the address), which can be perceived as practically unlimited.

Secondly, the amount of available address space in a typical C/C++ implementation depends on the memory type. There's static memory, there's automatic memory, there's dynamic memory. The address space limits for each memory type are pre-set in advance by the compiler. Which raises the question: where are you declaring your large array? Which memory type? Automatic? Static? You provided no information, but this is absolutely necessary. If you are attempting to declare it as a local variable (automatic memory), then no wonder it doesn't work, since automatic memory (aka "stack memory") has very limited address space assigned to it. Your array simply does not fit. Meanwhile, `malloc` allocates dynamic memory, which normally has the largest amount of address space available.

Thirdly, many compilers provide you with options that control the initial distribution of address space between different kinds of memory. You can request a much larger stack size for your program by manipulating such options. Quite possibly you can request a stack so large, than your local array will fit in it without any problems. But in practice, for obvious reasons, it makes very little sense to declare huge arrays as local variables.

Comment: Stack sizes can be controlled on runtime while starting threads both for phtreads and windows.

Comment: If stack memory wasn't limited, this site wouldn't make sense (or at least it's name)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming local variables, this is because on modern implementations automatic variables will be allocated on the stack which is very limited in space. This [link](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt) gives some of the common stack sizes:

```
platform    default size       
=====================================
SunOS/Solaris  8172K bytes
Linux          8172K bytes
Windows        1024K bytes
cygwin         2048K bytes
```

The linked article also notes that the stack size can be changed for example in Linux, one possible way from the shell before running your process would be:

> ulimit -s 32768    # sets the stack size to 32M bytes

While [malloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) on modern implementations will come from the heap, which is only limited to the memory you have available to the process and in many cases you can even allocate more than is available due to [overcommit](http://www.etalabs.net/overcommit.html).

Comment: Ok, I got it now, and what about the memory allocation by pointers...Doesnot that occur over the stack?

Comment: malloc() allocates on the heap, not the stack.  Different rules.

Comment: Perhaps add a note those common sizes can be overridden (in the binary resp. when creating the thread).

Comment: @AdityaBahuguna Also see [What and where are the stack and heap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap). If you can add some more code to your example it will help future readers.

Comment: Note that you can allocate memory on stack using [`alloca`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018853/why-is-alloca-not-considered-good-practice)

Comment: stack size is a just a parameter when starting a new thread - they are not fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I THINK you're missing the difference between total memory, and your programs memory space.  Your program runs in an environment created by your operating system.  It grants it a specific memory range to the program, and the program has to try to deal with that.

The catch: Your compiler can't 100% know the size of this range.

That means your compiler will successfully build, and it will REQUEST that much room in memory when the time comes to make the call to malloc (or move the stack pointer when the function is called).  When the function is called (creating a stack frame) you'll get a segmentation fault, caused by the stack overflow.  When the malloc is called, you won't get a segfault unless you try USING the memory.  (If you look at the manpage for malloc() you'll see it returns NULL when there's not enough memory.)

To explain the two failures, your program is granted two memory spaces.  The stack, and the heap.  Memory allocated using malloc() is done using a system call, and is created on the heap of your program.  This dynamically accepts or rejects the request and returns either the start address, or NULL, depending on a success or fail.  The stack is used when you call a new function.  Room for all the local variables is made on the stack, this is done by program instructions.  Calling a function can't just FAIL, as that would break program flow completely.  That causes the system to say "You're now overstepping" and segfault, stopping the execution.