# Access violation when using alloca

Tags: c++, c, malloc, alloca

My `stackAlloc` function looks like this:

```
void* stackAlloc(size_t size) {
    if (size > maxStackAllocation)
        return malloc(size);
    else 
        return _alloca(size);
}
void stackAllocFree(void *ptr, size_t size) {
    if (size > maxStackAllocation) {
        free(ptr);
    }
}
```

If I change so the `stackAlloc` function always use `malloc` instead of `alloca` everything works.

I changed the function to a macro, and now its working as expected:

```
#define maxStackAllocation 1024
#define stackAlloc(size) \
( \
    (size > maxStackAllocation)? \
         malloc(size): \
        _alloca(size) \
)

#define stackAllocFree(ptr, size) \
( \
    (size > maxStackAllocation)? \
        free(ptr): \
    void() \
)
```

Comment: What is the value of `maxStackAllocation`? I suggest you also read all of the warnings on the documentation page for `alloca`.

Comment: its 1024, I only allocate 124 bytes here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1029951/366904 (since Vulkan is apparently a C API, why not use variable-length arrays?)

Comment: Im using VS2015, it does not support it

Comment: @dev What are you talking about? His code works the way you describe. If `stackAlloc` calls `malloc`, then `stackAllocFree` calls `free`. There is no reason to free memory released with `_alloca`.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Please show an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show us how you call your `stackAlloc...` functios. The problem is not in the code you've showed in your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're running on Windows, since your code calls `_alloca()`, per the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb1s57t5.aspx):

> **_alloca** allocates *size* bytes from the program stack. The allocated space is automatically freed when the calling function exits

Note that the memory is freed when the calling function exits - which I'm assuming also means the calling function returns.

Your code:

```
void* stackAlloc(size_t size) {
    if (size > maxStackAllocation)
        return malloc(size);
    else 
        return _alloca(size);
}
```

returns, thus freeing the memory obtained via `_alloca()`.

Comment: I wonder if this applies if the function were marked `static inline __forceinline`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, of course it applies there as well. `alloca` is not a "real" malloc, it just subtracts more space from the stackpointer. This means that it will ALWAYS be automatically freed, because the CPU takes care of that. Therefore it doesn't matter wether a function is inline or not.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Inlining is not allowed to change the semantics of the inlined function. (Inlining is not a macro-like substitution.)

Comment: @Devolus I understand how `alloca` is implemented. If `esp` is subtracted in the (inlined) function, will the compiler add to `esp` immediately where the inlined function ends? Or will it forgo the cleanup until the calling function returns?

Comment: @molbdnilo For "normal" inlining, I agree. But `__forceinline` is non-standard, so it would be reasonable for something like `alloca` to "work" in this case. Either way, the "right" answer here is, make this `stackAlloc` a macro, or don't use `alloca` at all.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, A quick test in VS2010 shows that it does NOT clean up immediately, which is what I would have expected anyway. There is no reason to do it, as it doesn't change the rest of a function. What I wonder though is, what happens if you do multiple allocations so the total becomes bigger than 1024. IMO there is no strict reason for this size limit, because the stack can be bigger anway (though obviously smaller then using heap allocation).

Comment: @molbdnilo "_Inlining is not allowed to change the semantics of the inlined function_" says who?

Answer (score 3):

[From the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html),

> This temporary space is automatically freed
>          when the function that called alloca() returns to its caller.

So whenever your `stackAlloc` function returns, it will automatically free the memory.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I'd advise against using it in production:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <alloca.h>

auto stackAlloc(const size_t size)
{
    return [size](){ return alloca(size); };
}

int main() {
    char *ch = (char *)stackAlloc(40000)();
    ch[39999] = '\0';

    return 0;
}
```

Counter-check: if I decrease stackAlloc's parameter, it doesn't work (which is the expected behaviour here)
Feel free to add the check, etc. in stackAlloc (either by returning different lambdas or having the lambda do the check).