# Why couldn't `alloca` just return `NULL` in the event of a stack overflow?

Tags: c, stack-overflow

I'm writing a library in which I've found the non-standard C function `alloca` to be really useful. Several sources ([linux man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html), [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018853/why-is-the-use-of-alloca-not-considered-good-practice)) caution against using `alloca`. Unlike `malloc` and friends, which are supposed to return `NULL` when you run out of heap memory, using `alloca` is undefined behavior in the event of a stack overflow. In my case, I have hard limits (enforced by plenty of `assert` statements) on the sizes of the objects I'm allocating, so I think that this completely sensible caveat isn't an issue.

Nonetheless, I don't see why `alloca` necessarily has to result in undefined behavior in this circumstance. **Why couldn't `alloca` check where the stack pointer is and return `NULL` in the event of a possible stack overflow?** Implementing these checks would of course be platform- and architecture-specific, but I don't see why it should be impossible.

Comment: `alloca` is outdated. If you need a variable length array, use VLAs. But take note of their possibly different lifetime. That does not take the responsibility from you toensure enough stack is available, though.

Comment: `alloca()` _could_ return `NULL` in order to prevent a stack overflow.  It is not a standard C library function and there is insufficient call for to include it with your desired functionality.  It is not that it is impossible, it is lack of interest.  Note C does not even require a _stack_.

Comment: alloca does have its uses, But it does not check for a possible stack overflow, which can lead to undefined behaviour.