# Why does this code bit work in clion but doesn't in VS

Tags: c, linux, windows, visual-studio, clion

Hi I copied the following code from my linux machine with clion running. But in VS on Windows it seems to cause problems

```
entry_t* find_entry( char* n ) 
{
    // TODO (2)
    int x = strlen(n);
    char str[x];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        str[i] = toupper(n[i]);
    }

    n = &str;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < list_length; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(n, name_list[i].name) == 0)
        {
            return &name_list[i];
        }
    }
}
```

VS underlines the x in `char str[x];` before the statement do find x was in the brackets of str. I thought finding the length first in another variable would solve the problem

VS give the following error

Schweregrad Code    Beschreibung    Projekt Datei   Zeile   Unterdrückungszustand
Fehler (aktiv)  E0028   Der Ausdruck muss einen Konstantenwert aufweisen.   Names.exe - x64-Debug   C:\Users\Eyüp\source\repos\09\main.c    102

trying my best to translate it
-> Error(active) E0028 Statement needs to be a constant value

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't support Variable Length Arrays when using the Microsoft compiler. [How to use Visual Studio as an IDE with variable length array(VLA) working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58462881/how-to-use-visual-studio-as-an-ide-with-variable-length-arrayvla-working)

Comment: That looks like horrible piece of code anyway :D Best option would be to just replace `str[x]` with `malloc` and remember to free it before `return`l Also if none matches, your code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: `char str[x];` is not long enough and you are not adding the nul terminator.

Comment: It gets the job done :)

Comment: @Venox do you mean correcting it gets the job done, or that you are a victim of *undefined behaviour* who is deceived into thinking the mistakes are 'ok'?

Comment: @Venox: Re “It gets the job done :)”: No, it does not. You might not have observed a problem, but that does not mean one is not present. Unseen by you, the `strcmp` is overrunning the array. In a different C implementation or in different circumstances in the same C implementation, that will cause a crash, data corruption, or other problems. Do not be snarky and dismiss problems with “:)”. Computers are machines, and they will not forgive or overlook errors. Learn to program correctly, and pay attention to the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable-length arrays (i.e. arrays whose size is not known at compile-time) are not supported in MSVC because they don't care. Hence you need to use `malloc` and friends instead.

However that is not the only problem in your code: it has multiple undefined behaviours. Here is a suggested fix:

```
entry_t* find_entry( char* n ) 
{
    // return value of strlen is of type size_t, not int
    size_t x = strlen(n);

    // [x] was wrong, it needs to be [x + 1] for the null terminator!
    char *str = malloc(x + 1);

    // do not use strlen again in the loop. In worst case it does need 
    // to go through the entire string looking for the null terminator every time.
    // You must copy the null terminator, hence i <= x or i < x + 1
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= x; i++)
    {
        // the argument of toupper needs to be *unsigned char*
        str[i] = toupper((unsigned char)n[i]);
    }

    // why this did even exist? And it has type error anyway
    // n = &str;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < list_length; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(str, name_list[i].name) == 0)
        {
            // need to free the str...
            free(str);
            return &name_list[i];
        }
    }

    // in both paths...
    free(str);

    // add default return value
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code invokes undefined behaviour:

1. as you do not null terminate the string
2. you call `strlen` on not null terminated (and initially not initialized string)

The logic is also wrong.

```
entry_t* find_entry( const char* n ) 
{
    // TODO (2)
    size_t x = strlen(n);
    char str[x + 1];

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= x; i++)
    {
        str[i] = toupper((unsigned char)n[i]);
    }
    str[x] = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < list_length; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(str, name_list[i].name) == 0)
        {
            return &name_list[i];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

You need to return something if the sting was not found.

To use VLAs in VS [How to use Visual Studio as an IDE with variable length array(VLA) working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58462881/how-to-use-visual-studio-as-an-ide-with-variable-length-arrayvla-working)