# Microsoft VS and VS code did not use the same complier in the same window?

Tags: c++

This is my first time using `Microsoft VS 2022` (originally I use VS    code)
I first try this code in `Microsoft VS`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int convertStringToNumber(std::string a , int array[]){
    int temp=0;
    int size=a.length(); 
    for ( int i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
    array[i]=a[i] - '0';
    temp+=std::pow(10 , size-i-1)*array[i];}
    std::cout<<temp;
return temp;}

int main(){
    std::string a="12345";
    int size=a.length();
    int array[size]; //this works fine in VS code, but NOT in Microsoft VS 22
    int result=convertStringToNumber(a, array);
return 0; 
}
```

It gives error at the line above, which works fine in my VS code
My VS code is updated to the last version (with `g++ 13.1`)
Microsoft VS 2022 is set to the last vesion as well ( `IOS C++20` ) 
I also did try a lot of combinations of settings (to lower IOS ones) but it didn't work
I dont understand, didn't they use the same compiler? 
Why `My Microsoft VS 2022` didn't support that rather simple thing? How can I make my `My Microsoft VS 2022` support `array[size]`? 
I don't want to change the `array[]` to a vector which costs performance here. And it is also my favorite way to use `array[]` instead of a vecter (unless i have to) 
Any solution or setting to fix? Please help

Comment: VS Code is not your compiler, it is just an editor that happens to call the g++ compiler, which is different from VS which _does_ ship with its own compiler.

Comment: @Botje an extension on my Micro VS will help me fix that problem?

Comment: No, VS extensions only work on the editor part of the IDE. They do not affect the compiler.

Comment: Your statement "also costs performance" is also very disputable. If you are really counting cycles, create an empty `vector` and then use `reserve` to allocate memory for it without initializing. That is O(1).

Comment: Unrelated: `std::pow(10, x)` is an [antipattern and will lead to tears.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774912/gcc-c-pow-accuracy)

Comment: ah. so be that. I thought we should let things store them in the stack unless we have to store in on the heap

Comment: @Botje meaning I have no choice but have to use a vector here? :(

Comment: The most important reason for choosing stack over heap is "is this a variable local to this function and will it have to survive when my function ends or not"

Comment: Plainly put: as soon as you use VLAs you are no longer writing C++. In a professional setting you will not be allowed to use VLAs either. Vectors are a fine datastructure to use by default. [If you insist, this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58463020/1548468) suggests switching VS to use the Clang compiler, which does accept VLAs.

Comment: oh. may be the second option is to switch from C++ to another language too :D , thanks for your help @Botje

Comment: And you don't even *need* an array here. The convert function could use an `int digit = a[i] - '0';` for each digit in turn. Storing them all separately buys you nothing.

Comment: @BoP , right, in fact we don't need it, perhaps it only makes me feel more confident here

Comment: you can use `alloca` and do a placement-new of an `std::array`, which you can compile to the correct version of `alloca` of your compiler, keep in mind that `alloca` is the fastest way to get a stack-overflow, so be careful of its use.

Comment: correction, you should create an `std::span` that points to the allocated stack, as the size is only known at runtime.