# Is there a way to allocate stack memory for a char array? given that the length is known, however, the content will be added later on?

Tags: c++, opengl, memory

I've just started to learn OpenGL library.

I'm currently following a video tutorial of OpenGL.

Given the following code snippet to get the error message for shader compilation

```
int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (result == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char *message = (char *)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, message);
        std::cout << "Failed to compile " << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment")
                  << " shader" << std::endl;
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
        glDeleteShader(id);
        return 0;
    }
```

In the video i fololowed, the lecturer tried to first initialized message like so

```
char message[length];
```

However, as length is not a constant, it won't compile.

The way he went about it was to use the alloca function.

```
char *message = (char *)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
```

However, when i ran it through cppCheck, it says

> The obsolete function 'alloca' is called. In C++11 and later it is recommended to use std::array<> or a dynamically allocated array instead. The function 'alloca' is dangerous for many reasons ([Why is the use of alloca() not considered good practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018853/why-is-alloca-not-considered-good-practice) and http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca).

Is there any alternative to the alloca function that will still allow stack memory allocation for message?

Comment: Use a `std::vector`. You can get a pointer to the buffer backing it with the `data` method or with `&myvector[0]`.

Comment: ```std::string message(length, ' ');```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you feel the need to use stack space for this. It's an error handling function; performance is kind of irrelevant. So just use a `std::string`.

Comment: @user4581301 For storing a string, `std::string` is semantically better than `std::vector`.

Comment: It tells you: In C++ it is recommended to use a dynamically allocated array. (`std::array` does not apply because the size is not known)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, you have little choice for dynamically allocating memory on the stack. If you do not want to use `alloca`, then you can use `std::string` or other standard containers in your code. They are quite effective, despite the fact that they allocate memory on the heap.

In your code example, you really should not worry about memory allocation, unless the profiler indicates a decrease in performance.

If you are really concerned about memory management in C++, you can write your own management system using allocators. For example, you can allocate large fixed blocks of memory and then distribute them between data to avoid fragmentation. You can also reuse memory blocks. By independently managing the allocation and freeing of memory, you can make the heap as efficient as the stack.

For reference, see [std::allocator](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator), [Writing a Memory Allocator](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/compilers/writing-a-memory-allocator/).