# Why there is no compile error for the array definition with non-constant value?

Tags: c++, arrays

I thought I should get compile error for the following char array definition of the **allData**:

```
void MyClass::aMethod(const char* data, int size)
{
   int headerSize = 50;
   MyHeader header;
   //size is not constant and unknown at compile time
   char allData[size + headerSize]; //<<<<<==== should not allowed!! but not error??
   memcpy(allData, &header, headerSize);
   memcpy(allData + headerSize, data, size);
   ....
}
```

Why? It will give a run-time error?

Comment: Turn on -pedantic-errors.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312116/c-array-size-dependent-on-function-parameter-causes-compile-errors?rq=1

Comment: @chris I just tested it with -Werror -pedentic-errors -Wall with gcc and clang and the code compile fine.

Comment: You don't get an error, because ***it is not an error*** (provided you're using a C99 compiler, or a C++ compiler that supports it)

Comment: @abelenky it is an error for a standards compliant C++ compiler.

Comment: @GabrielL., Well, -pedentic-errors won't get you anywhere until you change the spelling.

Comment: @juanchopanza:   I think I was pretty clear about saying it is not an error if your compiler supports it.  Not all compilers are strictly 100% C++ compliant.

Comment: A diagnostic message is required for illegal code. A conforming compiler can choose to compile anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla) and possibly others although not [visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb1574zs.aspx), supports [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) an extension even though it is a *C99* feature not a C++ feature.

In both `gcc` and `clang` if you compile with `-pedantic` they will warn you that you are using extensions, for example `gcc` would produce a similar warning to this:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘allData’ [-Wvla]
```

and you can use `-pedantic-errors` to turn the warning into an error.

As far as I understand *C++14* may support *variable length arrays*. The C99 draft standard section `6.7.5.2` *Array declarators* says:

> [...] If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; **otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.**

while the C++ draft standard requires a constant, the draft C++ standard in section `8.3.4` *Arrays* says:

> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> > D1 [ constant-expressionopt] attribute-specifier-seqopt
>
> [..] If the constant-expression (5.19) is present, it shall be a converted constant expression of type std::size_t and its value shall be greater than zero. [...]

Answer (score 2):

Some C++ compilers have an option that allows to use C VLA in C++.