# array size defined from user's input C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am very surprised that the below code compiles fine. I always believed an array size must be a constant at compile time but it seems that I can take the user's input and use it as the array size. I am using GCC with the codeblocks IDE. Has anyone tried this and is there anything wrong with doing it?

```
int size;
cout<<"Enter array size : "<<endl;
cin>>size;
int arr[size];
// ...more action array with the array after which works fine
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why there is no compile error for the array definition with non-constant value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19775954/1708801)

Comment: First of, this is not C, and yes, it is perfectly valid.

Comment: Related: [VLAs in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)

Comment: @OldProgrammer No, it's not valid in C++, it would be valid to declare a VLA in C but C++ doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is called [Variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and is introduced in `C99` standard, just again to make it an optional feature in `C11` standard.

I do not have specific idea about `C++` standard, but this might be a support feature  which comes as a compiler extension. AFAIK, there is nothing in the `C++` standard that supports for VLA. Alternatively, using `std::vector` in `C++` is considered a better approach for this.

Comment: Would the array be still stored on the stack in this case?

Comment: @Engineer999 In `C`, `gcc` allocates the VLA [in stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#Memory). `std::vector` uses dynamic memory which is not allocated from stack, AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks. So by using the push_back function on vectors, does this create elements on the heap? Is that effectively the same as having pointers to an element type and using "new"